# Problem with UUID binary(16) when use Laravel relation orm

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, mariadb

I'm using uuid as a primary key of account table and it has many to many relations with role table. I store uuid in database as binary(16) thanks to a function i created called **UuidToBin** in mariadb convert a uuid string to binary(16) and when i want get uuid i use another function name is **UuidFromBin** convert uuid from binary(16) to string follow by this article: https://docs.w3cub.com/mariadb/guiduuid-performance/index. The problem is i can not retreive data when i use laravel eloquent relation because it auto pass the value of account table's primary key to join query with role table instead of call the function which convert uuid to binary(16) first so mariadb can compare.
The code relation:

**

```
public function roles () : BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'account_role',
                                'uuid_account', 'id_role');
}
```

**
The query laravel execute:

```
 select `role`.`id` from `role` inner join `account_role` on `role`.`id` = `account_role`.`id_role` 
    where `account_role`.`uuid_account` = '94cb6c01-3c6d-44fe-b40f-e798bb25d972'
```

The query i want:

```
    select `role`.`id` from `role` inner join `account_role` on `role`.`id` = `account_role`.`id_role` 
where `account_role`.`uuid_account` = UuidToBin('94cb6c01-3c6d-44fe-b40f-e798bb25d972')
```

If anyone know how to fix, or if there is a better way to work with uuid,  pls tell. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does Laravel have no way to call a "function"?

Comment: When you call relation in laravel orm, it will auto execute the first query above. I can not modify it to pass function into it by DB::raw() or something like that. If you know how, pls tell me

Comment: `<frustration>` There are a hundred SQL abstraction products (like Laravel) that _try_ to hide SQL from the user.  The users end up in forums like this one, asking how to do something or how to speed up the SQL.  Often the answer is to learn MySQL _in addition to the abstraction_ and use `::raw`.`</frustration>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soon, MariaDB will have a datatype called "UUID" that hides the packing/unpacking of UUIDs.

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26664

Experiment with it now in MariaDB 10.7, or wait for it to become "General Availability".

My [*UUID blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid) has been updated to mention 10.7 and give some hints on migration.

Comment: Thank you for information, is there anything like that in mysql. i see nothing diff between mysql and mariadb except that mysql have default function convert uuid to binary(16) and back

Comment: @PhạmTiếnHải - I updated my blog link today.  MySQL 8.0 only has bultin functions; MariaDB does not have the datatype before 10.7.

Comment: So i understand is the uuid datatype store 128 bytes of  an uuid right? Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @PhạmTiếnHải - Correct.  The `UUID` datatype is effectively `BINARY(16)` but with a special name. -- 128 bits of data.

Comment: So we can see and retreive the uuid data like a normal uuid string but mariadb will store it as binary(16), am i right? I dont know the "special name" you said above is

Comment: @PhạmTiếnHải - Datatype "UUID" instead of datatype "BINARY(16)".  Examples: "ENUM" and "TIMESTAMP" are just numbers under the covers.  For that matter, "CHAR(1)" is essentially an 8-bit "TINYINT UNSIGNED".  By having a special datatype, MariaDB knows to shuffle the 128 bits in a certain way when storing/fetching.  Compare: "TIMESTAMP" silently adds/subtracts the server's timezone to the internal integer.

Comment: Thank you for spending time to explain. I understand now.